# Facebook Messenger for Android with Google Maps

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-messenger

**UPDATE 1:** I filed [Bug Report 458407801389498](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/458407801389498/?disable_redirect=0) with Facebook and it has been assigned to engineering. I'll post an update once engineering has looked at it.

I am using a Generic Template with a URL Button in Facebook Messenger to provide a link to Apple Maps. **NOTE:** The same result occurs with a Google Maps URL. I apologize for not stating that up front. I tried that first, before creating this post.

```js
message: {
        attachment: {
          type: 'template',
          payload: {
            template_type: 'generic',
            elements: [
              {
                title: 'Directions to Sushi',
                default_action: {
                  type: 'web_url',
                  url: 'http://maps.apple.com/?q=Ootoya+Times+Square+NY',
                },
                buttons: [
                  {
                    type: 'web_url',
                    url: 'http://maps.apple.com/?q=Ootoya+Times+Square+NY',
                    title: 'Open in Maps',
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      },
```

It works great in iOS and launches Apple Maps.

[image: iOS Screenshot]

The Apple Maps URL supports detecting Android and providing the Google Maps equivalent link. On Android (v9) with the latest version of Messenger (223.0.0.11.119), I am struggling on how to get the URL to open in Chrome to launch the Google Maps app or just launch the external app.

In the Messenger Android App if I click on 'Follow link', it is using `webview` to render the Google Maps page instead of cross launching Google Maps.

[image: Android Screenshot 1 of 2]

If I tap the more actions and then 'Open in Chrome', it'll show the same 'Leaving Facebook' message but when I click 'Follow link' it will open Google Maps.

[image: Android Screenshot 2 of 2]

Any ideas on how I can resolve this? Thank you!

Comment: Better try with Google Maps URLs instead. They open Apple Maps when Google Maps for IOS is not installed and they open Google Maps for Android. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide

Comment: @LuísTavares It’s the same result with Google Maps. Also, the same occurs for Apple Maps URLs, they open Google Maps on Android devices. I’ll edit my post above to include it but I already tried using the Google Maps URL before creating this post. Also, as I stated above, if I elect to open the link in Chrome, it launches Google Maps on Android with both Apple Maps and Google Maps URLs. This is an issue within `webview` in Facebook Messenger.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 2:** I filed [Facebook Bug Report 458407801389498](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/458407801389498/?disable_redirect=0) regarding this issue. Facebook has stated that cross app launch functionality is not in Messenger's WebView in Android, by design. They did not elaborate as to why. I disagree with Facebook's assessment but I am just one small voice in the world of Facebook.

I know other people have faced this issue and I hope this helps them with a definitive answer from Facebook Developer Support.